# "There is no active transaction" when refreshing database in Laravel 8.0 test

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit

Using php 8.0.2 and Laravel 8.37.0, I am running tests where for every test the database data should be refreshed, since there is conflicting data per test (due to unique constraints).
using the in-memory database with SQLite, this works, but when I switch to MySQL (v8.0.23) I get the next error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\Controllers\AuthControllerTest::testSuccessLogin
PDOException: There is no active transaction
```

and the tests after this one fail due to data already inserted and not cleared after the test.

The the test that I am trying to do is:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\User\Company;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected array $connectionsToTransact = ['mysql'];

    public function testSuccessLogin(): void
    {
        $this->artisan('migrate-data');

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'email' => 'test@website.com'
        ]);

        $this->app->bind(UserRepository::class, function() use ($user) {
            return new UserRepository($user, new Company());
        });

        $loginResponse = $this->post('/api/login', [
            'email' => 'test@website.com',
            'password' => 'password'
        ]);

        $loginResponse->assertStatus(200);
        $loginResponse->assertJsonStructure([
            'data' => [
                'user' => [
                    'name',
                    'surname',
                    'email',
                    'abilities'
                ],
                'token',
            ]
       ]);
    }
}
```

and after executing this test and checking in the database, the data still exists. With and without the line `protected array $connectionsToTransact = ['mysql'];` gives me the same result.

My `phpunit.xml`-file look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
        <report>
            <html outputDirectory="reports/coverage"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <server name="DB_HOST" value="localhost"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value="mysql_test"/>
        <server name="DB_USERNAME" value="root"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Is this a known issue? Or am I missing someting?

Comment: Try removing `$connectionsToTransact`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, miken32. I tried that before, and it still doesn't work. When checking the source code, it sets a transaction up for all connections in that array, so it is a bit weird.

Comment: Everything done in a test with `RefreshDatabase` is always done in a transaction, so it's not necessary. The error message means something is trying to close a transaction that's already been closed, so I'd guess there's some conflict there.

Comment: This has happened to me in the past when I try to use RefreshDatabase to test code that makes use of transactions.  The internal code closing transactions appears to interfere with RefreshDatabase's transaction.

Comment: @Derek that's weird, because for me running a test that doesn't use transactions in the executed code also fails.

Comment: @EranMachiels Did you find an answer to that problem?

Comment: @Florian Falk No not yet

Comment: What does "Refresh" mean?  Perhaps "remove any data, then reload data from some static source"?  Perhaps it should even "drop and recreate tables"?  For that matter, also "drop and recreate the DATABASE"?  Which step do those?

Comment: MySQL's `Engine=MEMORY` knows nothing about "transactions".  Only `Engine=InnoDB`.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately all tables are using the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: @EranMachiels - (I was distracted by the mention of SQLite's in-memory table.)  What about the previous questions I asked?

Comment: @RickJames, Refresh in this context means: migrate database table once before all tests and CRUD data in a transaction. After the test completes the transaction is is rolled back, so the database is still clean and the migrations don't need to be refreshed (which takes a long time).

Comment: `ROLLBACK` of DDL statements was not possible before MySQL 8.0.  Perhaps you have found a case where it is failing.  Please provide an outline of the statements in the transaction.

Comment: @RickJames Which statements? I am using functions (this RefreshDatabase trait and the Query Builder) offered by Laravel. For specific code of this trait: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php. As soon as I do a CREATE statement I get the transaction error. Reading doesn't give it.

Comment: @EranMachiels did you find an explanation for this?

Comment: @DenisSpalenza Kinda. I noticed that this happens when you try to migrate anything after the transaction was started. I am using a library that uses the migrations in order to migrate data after the migrations (the `$this->artisan('migrate-data')` part in my code and that was causing the error. I now overwrite the RefreshDatabase trait to migrate both migrations and data-migration before starting the actual transaction for my tests. I'll post an official answer in this thread when I find the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out for the case I was having. I am using a library wich uses the migration logic to execute data migrations (hence the `$this->artisan('migrate-data');` in my code).
When using the `RefreshDatabase` trait, migrations are executed once and after that, a transaction is started. The migration logic does something with transactions, I think closing them afterwards, causing the error I was having.

The solution that worked for me, was to overwrite the `RefreshDatabase` trait to execute the data migrations before starting the transaction:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabaseState;

trait RefreshDatabaseWithData
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected function refreshTestDatabase(): void
    {
        if (! RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated) {
            $this->artisan('migrate:fresh', $this->migrateFreshUsing());
            $this->artisan('migrate-data'); // << I added this line

            $this->app[Kernel::class]->setArtisan(null);

            RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated = true;
        }

        $this->beginDatabaseTransaction();
     }
}
```

This is tested in Laravel 9 only, but I don't see why this wouldn't work on previous versions.

Answer (score 11):

The issue is that your test contains implicit commits and so ends the active transaction.

Re -

> "As soon as I do a CREATE statement I get the transaction error." -

`CREATE TABLE` etc are [statements that cause an implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html).

This in turn means the `RefreshDatabase` trait will not work because a rollback is not possible when the transaction is closed.

Hence `PDOException: There is no active transaction`

It seems to be a known issue/thrown error with php 8.0 - https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/35380

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it:

**Step 1:** Extend Connection class and override transaction method:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DBConnection;
use Closure;

class Connection extends DBConnection
{

    public function transaction(Closure $callback, $attempts = 1)
    {
        $callback($this);
    }
}
```

This override basically disables transactions internally, keeping your current code intact.

**Step 2:** Bind that concrete class to the abstract ConnectionInterface via a ServiceProvider (app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php would be a good place):

```
if(config('app.env')==='testing') {
   $this->app->bind(ConnectionInterface::class, Connection::class);
}
```

Notice that the binding is inside a condition against the environment. We want to apply this binding only when running tests.

If you're not using a .env.testing file for Unit Testing, I really recommend you to do it. It keeps everything much more cleaner. You can just copy .env to .env.testing and only update the DB_CONNECTION and DB_DATABASE constants, pointing to your test database.

Then define the .env.testing environment in phpinit.xml:

```
<php>
   <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
   <!-- <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="memory_testing"/> -->
   <!-- <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
</php>
```

Notice that I commented out DB_CONNECTION AND DB_DATABASE since those parameters will be fetched from .env.testing

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think this is the right way to solve this issue. With your solution, you are changing code you want to test in order for the tests to work. In that way, you still have no idea how your code would run in production, since it uses different implementations.

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround, but I'm not changing code, we're just delegating the transactions to the DatabaseTransactions trait, which does exactly what the Connection does. Whoever is responsible of coding and maintaining that trait, must be sure to keep it in sync with Connection's transactional functionality.

Laravel users should not be responsible of testing Laravel code (Laravel core devs do it for us). So we can expect Connection->transaction will do its job in production.

At the end, it's a simple begin -> commit -> rollback operation, which internally behaves exactly the same.