# Laravel 9 altering table in migration does not add new column

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, database-migration

How do I alter an existing table in Laravel 9, while running tests on sqlite database?

I have a migration like so, which alters the default users table migration.

**2022_07_27_151149_update_users_table.php**

```php
protected $tableName = 'users';

public function up()
{
    Schema::table($this->tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('first_name', 75);
        $table->string('last_name', 75);
        $table->string('mobile', 12);
        $table->dropColumn('name');
        dump('in closure'); // <--- this does fire
    });
    dump('completed up'); // <--- this does fire
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table($this->tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('name');
        
        if(Schema::hasColumn($this->tableName, 'first_name')){
            $table->dropColumn('first_name'); // this also gets upset if I don't wrap it as above
        }
        if(Schema::hasColumn($this->tableName, 'last_name')){
            $table->dropColumn('last_name');
        }
        if(Schema::hasColumn($this->tableName, 'mobile')){
            $table->dropColumn('mobile');
        }
    });
}
```

I have altered the factory to take into account these changes.

```php
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => fake()->firstName(),
        'last_name' => fake()->lastName(),
        'mobile' => fake()->phoneNumber(),
        'email' => fake()->safeEmail(),
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
}
```

But when used in any test I get exception `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table users has no column named first_name`

```php
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    use DatabaseMigrations, RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * @group debug
     */
    public function testDebug(): void
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create(); // <--- error here
        dd($user->toArray());
    }
}
```

How do I alter an existing table with migrations in sqlite for testing?

Of note: I have implemented the fix here to get past the no transaction issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/71761089/2244284

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get around this by making sure that drops are always in their own separate `Schema::table` callback. Like so:

```php
public function up()
{
    // add columns
    Schema::table($this->tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('first_name', 75);
        $table->string('last_name', 75);
        $table->string('mobile', 12);
    });

    // remove columns
    Schema::table($this->tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
        if(Schema::hasColumn($this->tableName, 'name')){
            $table->dropColumn('name');
        }
    });
}
```